# Readable Time Format (w/ Good Grammar!)

Tags: python, time, control-flow

I've been reading posts upon posts of the methods for converting an input number of seconds, which should be output as a formal string with given durations (hours, minutes, seconds). But I want to know how to format it so that it accounts for singularization/pluralization, when I know, for example, `62` seconds should read as `"1 minute and 2 seconds"` as opposed to `120` seconds which is simply `"2 minutes"`.

One other criteria is that it should return `"now"` if the seconds is `0`.

Here's my code so far:

```
def format_duration(seconds, granularity = 2):
    intervals = (('hours', 3600), ('minutes', 60), ('seconds', 1))
    human_time = []
    for name, count in intervals: 
        value = seconds // count
        if value: 
            seconds -= value * count
            if value == 1:
                name = name.rstrip('s')
            human_time.append("{} {}".format(value, name))
        else:
            return "now"
    return ','.join(human_time[:granularity])
```

Please help! Thanks!

MJ

Answer (score 2):

Your code already works quite nicely, you just have one problem with your `return "now"` that I fixed in the code below. What else do you want your code to do?

```
def prettyList(human_time):
    if len(human_time) > 1:
        return ' '.join([', '.join(human_time[:-1]), "and", human_time[-1]])
    elif len(human_time) == 1:
        return human_time[0]
    else:
        return ""

def format_duration(seconds, granularity = 2):
    intervals = (('hours', 3600), ('minutes', 60), ('seconds', 1))
    human_time = []
    for name, count in intervals: 
        value = seconds // count
        if value: 
            seconds -= value * count
            if value == 1:
                name = name.rstrip('s')
            human_time.append("{} {}".format(value, name))
    if not human_time:
        return "now"
    human_time = human_time[:granularity]
    return prettyList(human_time)
```

Edit: so I added a function to prettify the output, the last terms in the list will be separed by a "and" and all the others before by a comma. This will still work even if you add more intervals in your code (like `('days', 86400)`). The output now looks like `2 hours, 1 minute and 43 seconds` or `25 minutes and 14 seconds`.

Comment: this is actually very useful - currently my code is missing the proper "and" conjunction, say for an example like "1 minute and 2 seconds". My thought is that this is fixed with tweaking line 10, yes? Any ideas? The "and" needs to be there depending...

Comment: I guess you want the "and" for the last join, and commas for everything before, so that it outputs "2 hours, 1 minute and 58 seconds" ?

Comment: exactly! and that of course would apply to shorter durations too, where I wasn't accounting for hours, just minutes and seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: ok, given the current code, "1 minute and 2 seconds" uis currently showing as '1 minute,2 seconds' - clearly the join statement that needs tweaking.

Comment: It is done. As a side note, if you want to make your output even more "manmade", there is the [`num2words`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words) library that can convert your numbers to plain text.

Comment: i'm seeing the same thing. i also attempted to rework the original join statement to see if you could accommodate with the join statement from your prettylist function, but so far no result.

Comment: i'm not locating the change, can you specify which line please?

Comment: nvm, i see the change in the prettylist function. i'm on my last error! now it's saying '1 hour and 1 minute' should equal '1 hour, 1 minute and 2 seconds'

Comment: Are you sure you did not input a granularity of 2 instead of 3?

Comment: my granularity is set to 2, line 8

Comment: Then it's normal that you don't get the seconds, you'd need `granularity = 3` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Made some tweaks for readability :

```
def pretty_list(human_time):
    return human_time[0] if len(human_time) == 1 else ' '.join([', '.join(human_time[:-1]), "and", human_time[-1]])


def get_intervals(seconds):
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return (
        ("hour", h),
        ("minute", m),
        ("second", s)
    )


def format_duration(seconds, granularity=3):

    intervals = get_intervals(seconds)
    human_time = []
    for name, value in intervals:
        if value == 0:
            continue
        elif value == 1:
            human_time.append("{} {}".format(value, name))
        else:
            human_time.append("{} {}s".format(value, name))
    return (pretty_list(human_time[:granularity])) if len(human_time) != 0 else "now"
```

Comment: You can add the pretty_list part from @Efferalgan to get the best of both worlds!

Comment: i really like this one due to its readability, much easier to digest line for line, but it still doesn't account for the "and" needed in an example like "1 minute and 2 seconds"

Comment: Done! :) Divided the function too

Answer (score 1):

You can try to code for each variation:

```
def timestamp(ctime):
    sec = int(ctime)
    if sec == 0:
        return "Now"
    m, s = divmod(sec, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    if h == 1: hr_t = 'Hour'
    else: hr_t = 'Hours'
    if m == 1: mn_t = 'Minute'
    else: mn_t = 'Minutes'
    if s == 1: sc_t = 'Second'
    else: sc_t = 'Seconds'
    time_stamp = ""
    if h > 0 and m ==0 and s ==0:
        time_stamp = "%02d %s " % (h, hr_t)
    elif h > 0:
        time_stamp = "%02d %s, " % (h, hr_t)
    if m > 0 and s !=0:
        time_stamp = time_stamp +"%02d %s and %02d %s" % (m, mn_t, s, sc_t)
    elif m > 0 and s == 0:
        time_stamp = time_stamp +"%02d %s" % (m, mn_t)
    elif m == 0  and s != 0:
        time_stamp = time_stamp +"%02d %s" % (s, sc_t)
    return time_stamp
print (timestamp(11024))
print (timestamp(0))
print (timestamp(31))
print (timestamp(102))
print (timestamp(61))
print (timestamp(60))
print (timestamp(3600))
print (timestamp(3632))
03 Hours, 03 Minutes and 44 Seconds
Now
31 Seconds
01 Minute and 42 Seconds
01 Minute and 01 Second
01 Minute
01 Hour 
01 Hour, 32 Seconds
```

Or you can use the `relativedelta` option in `dateutil` and then pick the bones out of it.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
attrs = ['years', 'months', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']
human_readable = lambda delta: ['%d %s ' % (getattr(delta, attr), getattr(delta, attr) != 1 and attr   or attr[:-1]) for attr in attrs if getattr(delta, attr) or attr == attrs[-1]]
readable=''
for i in human_readable(relativedelta(seconds=1113600)):
    readable += i
print readable
print human_readable(relativedelta(seconds=13600))
print human_readable(relativedelta(seconds=36))
print human_readable(relativedelta(seconds=60))
print human_readable(relativedelta(seconds=3600))
12 days 21 hours 20 minutes 0 seconds 
['3 hours ', '46 minutes ', '40 seconds ']
['36 seconds ']
['1 minute ', '0 seconds ']
['1 hour ', '0 seconds ']
```

For more examples of the second example see: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578113-human-readable-format-for-a-given-time-delta/
which is where I stole almost all the second set of code from

Comment: I was going to post something along these lines. Thanks for sparing me the research :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it! I actually needed more intervals - the durations asked for were lengthier than I thought...

```
def prettyList(human_time):
    if len(human_time) > 1:
        return ' '.join([', '.join(human_time[:-1]), "and", human_time[-1]])
    elif len(human_time) == 1:
        return human_time[0]
    else:
        return ""

def format_duration(seconds, granularity = 4):
    intervals = (('years', 29030400), ('months', 2419200), ('weeks', 604800),('days', 86400),('hours', 3600), ('minutes', 60), ('seconds', 1))
    human_time = []
    for name, count in intervals: 
        value = seconds // count
        if value: 
            seconds -= value * count
            if value == 1:
                name = name.rstrip('s')
            human_time.append("{} {}".format(value, name))
    if not human_time:
        return "now"
    human_time = human_time[:granularity]
    return prettyList(human_time)
```

Comment: woops! now it's saying '6 months, 2 weeks, 1 hour and 44 minutes' should equal '182 days, 1 hour, 44 minutes and 40 seconds'......any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean? You input the number of seconds corresponding to 6 months, and it outputs "182 days etc."?

Comment: for some reason, it's asking for days, hours, minutes, and seconds now.

Comment: @Efferalgan any thoughts?

Comment: I think that your problem is that a month is not a fixed amount of time: it can be either 30, 31, 28 or 29 days long.

Comment: well, based on the error, it's saying that my output breaks down 182 days, which it wants to see, into 6 months and 2 weeks, which is the same thing.

Comment: please help, i'm stuck!

Comment: The second piece of code from @Rolf of Saxony seems way better than anything we came up with. Did you try it?

Comment: here's my revised code, which is now reading right, but....problem is that my last test reads "'26 weeks, 1 hour, 44 minutes and 40 seconds' should equal '182 days, 1 hour, 44 minutes and 40 seconds' - 26 weeks is 182 days, so i thought maybe it's the granularity? i'm unsure.

Comment: So 26 weeks is 182 days, and your program says that 26 weeks is 182 days? Then what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that it wants it to read 182 days, not 26 weeks - the measurement of days would precede weeks, so if they're the same value, then days by default would show up first. problem is i can't figure out why that is.

Comment: I just tried your code, without changing anything. With an input of `182*60*60*24+60*60*1+60*44+40` (ie 182 days, 1 hour, 44 minutes and 40 seconds), I get the output `6 months, 2 weeks, 1 hour and 44 minutes`. And that seems quite right.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have covered all of the bases here but I'm sure someone will let me know if I have made an error (large or small) :)

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
def convertdate(secs):
    raw_date = relativedelta(seconds=secs)
    years, days = divmod(raw_date.days, 365) # To crudely cater for leap years / 365.2425
    hours = raw_date.hours
    minutes = raw_date.minutes
    seconds = raw_date.seconds
    full = [years,days,hours,minutes,seconds]
    date_text=['','','','','']
    if years == 1: date_text[0] = "Year"
    else: date_text[0] = "Years"
    if days == 1: date_text[1] = "Day"
    else: date_text[1] = "Days"
    if hours == 1: date_text[2] = "Hour"
    else: date_text[2] = "Hours"
    if minutes == 1: date_text[3] = "Minute"
    else: date_text[3] = "Minutes"
    if seconds == 1: date_text[4] = "Second"
    else: date_text[4] = "Seconds"
    first_pos = 0
    final_pos = 0
    element_count = 0
    # Find the first and final set positions and the number of returned values
    for i in range(5):
        if full[i] != 0:
            final_pos = i
            element_count +=1
            if first_pos == 0:
                first_pos = i
    # Return "now" and any single value
    if element_count == 0:
        return "Now"
    if element_count == 1:
        return "%02d %s" % (full[final_pos],date_text[final_pos])
    # Initially define the separators
    separators=['','','','','']
    ret_str=''
    for i in range(4):
        if full[i] != 0:
            separators[i] = ', '
    separators[final_pos] = ''
    # Redefine the final separator
    for i in range(4,-1,-1):
        if separators[i] == ', ':
            separators[i] = ' and '
            break
    #Build the readable formatted time string
    for i in range(5):
        if full[i] != 0:
            ret_str += "%02d %s%s" % (full[i],date_text[i],separators[i])
    return ret_str
print convertdate(1111113601)
print convertdate(1111113635)
print convertdate(1111113600)
print convertdate(1111111200)
print convertdate(1111104000)
print convertdate(1111104005)
print convertdate(11113240)
print convertdate(11059240)
print convertdate(11113600)
print convertdate(36)
print convertdate(60)
print convertdate(61)
print convertdate(121)
print convertdate(122)
print convertdate(120)
print convertdate(3600)
print convertdate(3601)

35 Years, 85 Days, 02 Hours, 40 Minutes and 01 Second
35 Years, 85 Days, 02 Hours, 40 Minutes and 35 Seconds
35 Years, 85 Days, 02 Hours and 40 Minutes
35 Years, 85 Days and 02 Hours
35 Years and 85 Days
35 Years, 85 Days and 05 Seconds
128 Days, 15 Hours and 40 Seconds
128 Days and 40 Seconds
128 Days, 15 Hours, 06 Minutes and 40 Seconds
36 Seconds
01 Minute
01 Minute and 01 Second
02 Minutes and 01 Second
02 Minutes and 02 Seconds
02 Minutes
01 Hour
01 Hour and 01 Second
```